# Пунктуация. Допустимо ли поставить двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

Допустимо ли поставить двоеточие в предложении: "Мне нравились попутчики: завораживало таинство их жизни, открытое мне случайно, как бы мимоходом"?

Answer (score 1):

Да, так как далее — значение причины (можно мысленно подставить союз "потому что").

> Двоеточие ставится между двумя предложениями, не соединенными посредством союзов, если в первом предложении такими глаголами, как *видеть, смотреть, слышать, знать, чувствовать* и т. п., делается предупреждение, что далее последует изложение какого-нибудь факта или какое-нибудь описание.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что во второй части этого предложения, которая распространена и причастным оборотом, и уточнением, нет значения причины (то есть предполагать подстановку "потому что" — неверно).

Я вижу такой смысл: попутчики мне нравятся просто так, сами по себе (в пути симпатии между путешественниками возникают довольно часто), но к этому ещё и завораживает приоткрытая ими тайна (которую без взаимной приязни тебе никто не раскроет).

Тогда предложение может иметь такой вид (можно вставить союз **и**):
*Мне нравились попутчики, и* [меня] *завораживало таинство их жизни, открытое мне случайно, как бы мимоходом.*

Или такой (при прямом порядке слов, без инверсии):
*Мне нравились попутчики —* [а] *таинство их жизни, открытое мне случайно, как бы мимоходом, завораживало.*

Между двумя самостоятельными предложениями я бы поставила тире или точку с запятой.

[Знаки препинания между частями бессоюзного предложения](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185)

Answer (score 1):

**Это предложение из тотального диктанта,** возможная постановка двоеточия в нем обсуждалась на форумах.

Алексей Иванов. Текст 2014 года. Поезд Чусовская – Тагил

**Часть 2. Поезд и люди**

*Тогда, в детстве, всё было по-другому: и дни длиннее, и земля больше, и хлеб не привозной. **Мне нравились попутчики, завораживало таинство их жизни, открытое мне случайно, как бы мимоходом.** Вот чистенькая старушка разворачивает газетку, в которой аккуратно сложены перья лука, пирожки с капустной начинкой и яйца, сваренные вкрутую. Вот небритый папаша укачивает сидящую у него на коленях маленькую дочку...*

Итак, мальчику интересно наблюдать за попутчиками. По внешности, по отдельным эпизодам он пытается представить их жизнь, как бы разгадать тайну их бытия.

Причина вроде бы названа, но  **взаимообусловленность в тексте не обозначена, интонация перечислительная, паузы нет**. Ведь в чувствах трудно разобраться и сразу объяснить их однозначно следующим образом: попутчики нравились именно потому,  что завораживали...

Поэтому в авторском тексте стоит **запятая, которая соответствует интонации** (текст ведь читался!).

**Это БСП, второе предложение  распространяет первое предложение** (продолжает его тему). Взаимообусловленность предложений не обозначается, хотя она и присутствует.

Но это в авторском тексте, а **можно ли всё-таки поставить двоеточие, будет ли это ошибкой?**

Я думаю, что **постановка двоеточия (или лучше тире) не противоречит правилам,** хотя и не соответствует авторскому пониманию текста. Ведь предполагаемая причина того, почему нравились попутчики, всё-таки названа, да и прочтение предложения с паузой тоже вполне допустимо.

Answer (score 1):

Двоеточие в бессоюзном предложении ставится, если после первой части следует пояснение того, о чем идет речь в первой части, например: Напишите план работы: что нужно закупить и подготовить, с чего требуется начать, в какие сроки возможно завершение проекта» или Как все московские ваш батюшка таков: желал бы зятя он с звездами да с чинами (Грибоедов). В эти предложения между частями можно вставить союз А ИМЕННО;

Мне нравились попутчики: завораживало таинство их жизни, открытое мне случайно, как бы мимоходом.

Двоеточие можно поставить, так как во второй части идет пояснение того, о чем говорится в первой, можно между частями вставить союз А ИМЕННО:

Мне нравились попутчики, а именно: завораживало таинство их жизни, открытое мне случайно, как бы мимоходом.